# Binding multiple events on same widget to the same callback function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Have a look at the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApp():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scr_w = parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        scr_h = parent.winfo_screenheight()
        parent.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(1280, 766, scr_w//4, scr_h//4))
        parent.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<Left>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<Right>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<Up>', self.callback)
        parent.bind('<Down>', self.callback)

    def callback(self, e):
        print(e)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

What I try to do is, bind multiple, different events for the *same* widget to the *same* callback function. In this example, there are only three events that trigger callback(), but imagine that in my real code I have several keys that must trigger the same callback function.

Is there a way to do this in `tkinter` with a single `bind()` statement instead of having a separate `bind()` statement for each and every individual event?

Comment: What's wrong with having separate bind statements?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it works. But this occurs so frequently in my code that I end up with a lot, I mean a LOT, of repetitions. It takes the focus away from what I consider to be the 'real important' parts of the code. It seems such a simple request... ;-)  Imagine what the code would look like if I wanted to bind half of the keyboard to the same callback function (which is fortunately not the case).

Comment: Keyboard events are easy, but your question seems to be asking about mouse buttons.

Comment: That's correct. I'm using combinations of mouse-events and keyboard-events that all trigger the same callback. But please share your answer for key-event bindings if you want to? I'm sure it will be helpful for me.

Comment: I changed my post to give a more realistic example of what is actually happening in my code.

Comment: You can always define your own `multibind()` function that takes multiple events (as a list, as separate parameters, or as a delimited string) and loops over them to do the bindings.

Comment: If it is not directly possible with tkinter, then your suggestion is not a bad idea at all. It certainly cleans up my code! Would be nice if I could do it by extending an existing tkinter class...

Answer (score 2):

Keypresses are easy. You can bind to `<Any-Keypress>`, and the event object that is passed to the callback can be used to determine which key was pressed.

You can also bind to `<Any-ButtonPress>` as well. You will need a distinct binding for the motion events.

Comment: Stupid me, that is exactly what I'm doing for the arrow keys right now, except that I bind them individually. Pure theoretically: that would only work as long as I do no need to bind (let's say a <Shift-Up>) to a different callback. Right?